# Label multiply defined warning but I only have one label LNCS template

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, theorems

Not a huge deal but I'm getting a strange warning  Label `PolyApx' multiply defined.   even though I only have one label in my entire document.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{environ}
\newcommand{\repeattheorem}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\ref{#1}}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\theorem
  \csname reptheorem@#1\endcsname
  \endtheorem
  \endgroup
}

\NewEnviron{reptheorem}[1]{%
  \global\expandafter\xdef\csname reptheorem@#1\endcsname{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
  }%
  \expandafter\theorem\BODY\unskip\label{#1}\endtheorem
}
\begin{document}
%
\title{adsnvuadsipnvewjl\thanks{Supported by University of Alberta}}
 \author{Hao Sun\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-0002-2000-8080} 
 }
%
\authorrunning{Hao Sun}
\institute{University of Alberta, Alberta, Canada}
%
\maketitle            
%
\begin{abstract}
 jasdkflasdgfhudafyhebvkcyfhdsuifgakhewnfcgyuzshvcdsyuafcgkdsh 
nbcvasdkfhvuban,vcyuaebvndskaguyrhvba.
\keywords{advdasv dav}
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
Our problem is one of Karp's original 21 NP-hard problems \cite{Karp1972}. 

\begin{reptheorem}{thmDFVSapprox}\label{PolyApx}
jsafhlsdajlkfhdsjaklfdshfjasldfjdskafhdjskflhasdjkfldsha
\end{reptheorem}

adfasdf \autoref{PolyApx}

\repeattheorem{thmDFVSapprox}
adsfasdf \autoref{PolyApx}
 \bibliographystyle{splncs04}
 \bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your environment does `\label{#1}` so your theorem already has `\label{thmDFVSapprox}` but then you add `\label{PolyApx}` which is on the body of the environment so saved and executed twice when you repeat it, so that label generates the  warning when you repeat it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  But that's in the preamble so are all restatables labelled with \label{#1}?

Comment: #1 is the first argument so it will be a different label each time, but in the one use you showed it is thmDFVSapprox

Answer (score 1):

As [David Carlisle wrote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700203/label-multiply-defined-warning-but-i-only-have-one-label-lncs-template#comment1740643_700203), you can just use `\autoref` on the label for the `\repeattheorem`, and shouldn't use a separate `\label` in the theorem statement.

See the following, which should generate the desired output.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{environ}
\newcommand{\repeattheorem}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\ref{#1}}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\theorem
  \csname reptheorem@#1\endcsname
  \endtheorem
  \endgroup
}

\NewEnviron{reptheorem}[1]{%
  \global\expandafter\xdef\csname reptheorem@#1\endcsname{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
  }%
  \expandafter\theorem\BODY\unskip\label{#1}\endtheorem
}
\begin{document}
%
\title{adsnvuadsipnvewjl\thanks{Supported by University of Alberta}}
 \author{Hao Sun\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-0002-2000-8080} 
 }
%
\authorrunning{Hao Sun}
\institute{University of Alberta, Alberta, Canada}
%
\maketitle            
%
\begin{abstract}
 jasdkflasdgfhudafyhebvkcyfhdsuifgakhewnfcgyuzshvcdsyuafcgkdsh 
nbcvasdkfhvuban,vcyuaebvndskaguyrhvba.
\keywords{advdasv dav}
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
Our problem is one of Karp's original 21 NP-hard problems \cite{Karp1972}. 

\begin{reptheorem}{thmDFVSapprox}
jsafhlsdajlkfhdsjaklfdshfjasldfjdskafhdjskflhasdjkfldsha
\end{reptheorem}

adfasdf \autoref{thmDFVSapprox}

\repeattheorem{thmDFVSapprox}
adsfasdf \autoref{thmDFVSapprox}
 \bibliographystyle{splncs04}
 \bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```